# Create pull request with github action

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I'm trying to make it work this action, but I'm confused also whats it's missing in between, before triggering the peter-evans PR.

The scenario is pretty simple, I like on push, on any feature/* branch, to create automatically PR, but instead I'm getting weird scenario, where develop changes are applied on top of the feature/* branch. Can someone give me hints on this?

```
name: Pull Request Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*

jobs:
  create-pull-request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: develop
      
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3.10.0
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          commit-message: Simple demo
          title: '[Example] Simple demo'
          body: >
            This PR is auto-generated by 
            [create-pull-request](https://github.com/peter-evans/create-pull-request).
          labels: feature, automated pr
          branch: feature/workflow-demo
```

Answer (score 87):

I know this question is a year old now and asking about the `create-pull-request` action, but for those that would rather not use third-party actions,  Github actions now support [Github command line](https://cli.github.com/) natively, if you use  Github hosted runners. See: [Using Github CLI in Workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows)

This makes it super easy to create a pull request using the [gh pr create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) command

Something like this:

```
  steps:
    - name: create pull request
      run: gh pr create -B base_branch -H branch_to_merge --title 'Merge branch_to_merge into base_branch' --body 'Created by Github action'
      env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Make sure you also enable `Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests` under `Settings > Actions` in your repository

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score 37):

Just posting this as an alternative solution. If you don't want to use any 3rd party actions you can achieve this with `actions/github-script`, it will just require a bit more coding.

As this stands, the action will error if there is already an open PR for the feature branch. If this is an issue you could check of an existing PR with the `github.rest.pulls.list` method, filtering by both `head` and `base` so it will only return one or no PRs.

```yaml
name: Pull Request Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*
      
jobs:
  create-pull-request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const { repo, owner } = context.repo;
            const result = await github.rest.pulls.create({
              title: '[Example] Simple demo',
              owner,
              repo,
              head: '${{ github.ref_name }}',
              base: 'develop',
              body: [
                'This PR is auto-generated by',
                '[actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script).'
              ].join('\n')
            });
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              owner,
              repo,
              issue_number: result.data.number,
              labels: ['feature', 'automated pr']
            });
```

Comment: Is there a way to add reviewers or teams (code owners) for the PR in scope of this script?

Comment: @AdamJensen you should be able to use `github.rest.pulls.requestReviewers()`, docs are here: https://github.com/octokit/plugin-rest-endpoint-methods.js/blob/main/docs/pulls/requestReviewers.md

Answer (score 7):

Reading through the readme, the action by Peter Evans doesn't fit what you're trying to achieve. But you can use [repo-sync's pull-request action](https://github.com/repo-sync/pull-request):

```
name: Pull Request Action
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/*

jobs:
  create-pull-request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: pull-request
        uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2
        with:
          destination_branch: "develop"
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pr_label: "feature, automated pr"
          pr_title: "[Example] Simple demo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @Grabofus , the action will fail if there's already an existing and open PR for the same `head` and `base`. This can be solved by checking for an existing PR prior to creating a new one:

```yaml
  create_pull_request:
    name: 'Create PR'
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/beta'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      - deploy
    permissions:
      pull-requests: write
    steps:
      - name: 'Create PR'
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const { repo, owner } = context.repo;
            const pulls = await github.rest.pulls.list({
              owner: owner,
              repo: repo,
              head: context.ref,
              base: 'main',
              state: 'open',
            });
            
            if (pulls.data.length < 1) {
              await github.rest.pulls.create({
                title: '[CI] Merge beta into main',
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                head: context.ref,
                base: 'main',
                body: [
                  'This PR is auto-generated by',
                  '[actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script)',
                ].join('\n'),
              });
            } else {
              const existingPR = pulls.data[0];
              await github.rest.pulls.update({
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                pull_number: existingPR.number,
                body: [
                  existingPR.body,
                  `Updated by Job ${context.job}`,
                ].join('\n'),
              });
            }
```

Instead of updating the description like in the example above, you can of course also decide to do nothing or for example add a instead comment like so:

```js
            } else {
              const existingPR = pulls.data[0];
              await github.rest.issues.createComment({
                owner: owner,
                repo: repo,
                issue_number: existingPR.number,
                body: [
                  `Updated by Job ${context.job}`,
                ].join('\n'),
              });
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You might need to specify the base branch there:

```
- name: Create Pull Request
    uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v3.10.1
    with:
      token: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
      commit-message: Auto Pull Request
      title: Your desired title
      body: Auto-created Pull Request
      branch: ${{ github.ref }} # The branch where you commit
      base: develop # Don't forget to specify the right base branch here
```

I have this and it creates the PR when it does not exist. I remember it didn't work exactly right at the beginning until I specified myself `base` and `branch` values, which are not very clear in the docs.