# How to create a GitHub action to open a pull request with the parent repo

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I want to create a GitHub action so that on a push to the main branch of a forked GitHub repo, a pull request will be generated for the GitHub parent repo main branch. How can I do this?

I am a newbie on this and cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create pull request with github action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057744/create-pull-request-with-github-action)

Comment: Not quite since it looks like peter-evans/create-pull-request does not handle pull requests between ropos.

Comment: As [outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73340290/367456), use the [gh pr create](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) command **against your specific repository** (compare [gh auth](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth)).

Comment: @hakre As far as I can determine the gh command cannot create a PR between two different GitHub repos (as opposed to creating a PR within a single repo).

Comment: Hmm, I'd say it can (ref https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create), but we perhaps talk about different things. `gh` creating a pr can at least create a new fork in case you need it (if that counts as different GitHub repos in your book, it would in mine).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really want any new repos. I'm reconsidering my entire approach. So creating a PR within a single repo looks like it would work for what I want even though it is not a solution to my original question.

Comment: Yes, you don't want, but git is a distributed version control system, that is you get new git repositories all the time. Every checkout in a Github action is creating a new git repository. So if you comment here you don't want a new repository, then not only creating a PR on Github but using Git at all is problematic. Please clarify what blocks you on creating a pull request with the `gh` command in the repository you want. Add all clarifications to your question by editing it, not in comments below.